# R Markov chain output iteration

Tags: r

I am currently using markovchain package for my analysis.

I have (a,b,c,d) for states,

I need to output a dataset, which contains proportion of a,b,c,d at each iteration. my codes are:

## 1.define states and transition probabilities

```
library(markovchain)
state<-c("a", "b","c","d");
tp<-matrix(data=c(0.721, 0.202,0.067,0.010,0,0.581,0.407,0.012,0,0,0.75,0.25,0,0,0,1),byrow=T, nrow=4, dimnames=list(state,state));
```

## 2.define initial state and markov chain

```
s0<-c(1,0,0,0)
mcHIV<-new("markovchain", states=state,byrow=T,transitionMatrix=tp,name="HIV")
```

## 3.do 20 iterations I HAVE PROBLEMS HERE!!

```
sq1<-seq(1,20)
s<-NULL

for (n in 1:20){s[n]<-mcHIV^sq1[n]};
```

Error in s[n] <- mcHIV^sq1[n] : 
  invalid type/length (S4/0) in vector allocation**

How shoud I handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Since the output is a matrix you need to create a list:

```
s <- list()
for (n in 1:20){s[[n]] <- mcHIV^sq1[n]};
```

Each element of the list, `s[[1]]`, `s[[2]]`, ..., `s[[k]]` will refer to the state of the transition matrix after iteration `k`

An better way to do this programmatically is to use `lapply` which returns a list of objects, in this case, the transition matrices:

```
iter <- 20
s <- lapply(seq(iter), function(k) mcHIV^k)
```

Still accessible by `s[[1]]`, `s[[2]]`, ..., `s[[k]]`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have one more question: when I did  e.g. s10<-s0*mcHIV^10,   the results are like [1,] 0.03796231 0.0484503 0.2335559 0.6800315. However, based on the iteration, for S10, I will get a matrix? why?

Comment: @SunSynergus `s0` is a vector, or a matrix of dimension 1 x 4, so when you multiply `mcHIV^10` (a 4 x 4 matrix), the result is a (1 x 4) x (4 x 4) = (1 x 4) matrix, or in other words a vector.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (n in 1:20){s<-c(s,mcHIV^sq1[n])};
```

You can create a list of matrices to store the desired result.